# Javascript assumes a string with a space as an operable value

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

When user types on this application a single space, JavaScript assumes it's an operable value ([DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ts0bkntf/)):

```
var num;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    num = prompt("Number plz", "Number here...");
    if (num < 10) {
        alert("Lower 10");
    } else if (isNaN(num)) {
        alert("Unoperable...");
    }
}
```

What's the reason behind this behaviour?

The only way to detect a blank space would be with regular expressions?

Comment: Javascript is loosely typed, anything can be compared to anything, really

Comment: Make sure you cast string to number `Number(prompt("Number plz", "Number here..."))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [value returned by `prompt` will be a String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt#Syntax). And you are comparing a string and a number in this line

```
if (num < 10) {
```

When comparing values of two different types, type coercion happens and then the values will be compared. In your case, when you enter empty string, `num` will be coerced to a number to get `0`.

```
console.log(Number(' '));
// 0
```

Since `0 < 10` you are seeing the alert.

You might want to read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)

---

You should actually convert the value returned by `prompt` to a number, like this

```
num = parseInt(prompt("Number plz", "Number here..."), 10);
```

and then swap the conditions like this

```
if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("Unoperable...");
} else if (num < 10) {
    alert("Lower 10");
}
```

---

**Note:** Even, `parseInt` accepts numbers even if they are followed by characters which are not digits. For example,

```
console.log(parseInt('123abc456def'));
// 123
```

So, to be absolutely sure, you need to check if the string has only digits, like this

```
num = prompt("Number plz", "Number here...");
if (/^\d+$/.test(num)) {
    alert("Unoperable...");
} else if (parseInt(num, 10) < 10) {
    alert("num < 10");
}
```

Here, `^\d+$` means that from the beginning of the string (`^`) till the end of string (`$`), there should be one or more (`+`, if it is `*`, it means zero or more) digits (`\d`)